# Print an ArrayList of an object in a table format

Tags: java, object, arraylist

Basically I wrote this code where the user inputs certain values for members of a class. I also made an `ArrayList` of that class. I want to code it in such a way that the user could ask the program to print all the data he/she input, but I can't seem to get it work.

Jobs:

```
public class Jobs {

    protected float CostPerHour, HoursWorked, CostOfMaterials, CostOfJob;
    protected String Date, JobNumber;

    public Jobs(String JobNumber, String Date, float CostPerHour, float CostOfMaterials, float HoursWorked){
        this.JobNumber = JobNumber;
        this.Date = Date;
        this.CostPerHour = CostPerHour;
        this.HoursWorked = HoursWorked;
        this.CostOfMaterials = CostOfMaterials;
        this.CostOfJob = CostOfJob(CostPerHour, CostOfMaterials, HoursWorked);
        System.out.println("Job has been added to the list.");
    }

    public float CostOfJob(float CostPerHour, float CostOfMaterials, float HoursWorked){
        CostOfJob = CostPerHour*HoursWorked + CostOfMaterials;
        System.out.println("The cost for this job is "+ CostOfJob);
        return CostOfJob;
    }

    public float getCostPerHour() {
        return CostPerHour;
    }

    public float getHoursWorked() {
        return HoursWorked;
    }

    public float getCostOfMaterials() {
        return CostOfMaterials;
    }

    public float getCostOfJob() {
        return CostOfJob;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return Date;
    }

    public String getJobNumber() {
        return JobNumber;
    }      
}
```

JobTester:

```
public class JobTester {

    static ArrayList<Jobs> jobs = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String [] args){

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        float CostPerHour, HoursWorked, CostOfMaterials;
        String Date, JobNumber;
        String option = "y";

        while((option.equals("y"))||(option.equals("Y"))){
            System.out.print("Please Enter the Date : ");
            Date = keyboard.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Please Enter the Job Number : ");
            JobNumber = keyboard.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Please Enter the Cost Per Hour : ");
            CostPerHour = keyboard.nextFloat();
            System.out.print("Please Enter the Number of Hours : ");
            HoursWorked = keyboard.nextFloat();
            System.out.print("Please Enter the Cost of Materials : ");
            CostOfMaterials = keyboard.nextFloat();
            keyboard.nextLine(); 
            jobs.add(new Jobs(JobNumber, Date, CostPerHour, CostOfMaterials, HoursWorked));

            System.out.print("Press Y to create a new Job : ");
            option = keyboard.nextLine();        
        }

        System.out.print("Press Y to print the list of jobs you created : ");
        option = keyboard.nextLine();

        if((option.equals("y"))||(option.equals("Y"))){
            PrintJobs();
        }

        System.out.print("Press any key to exit.");
        keyboard.nextLine();

    }
    public static void PrintJobs(){
        System.out.println("Date \tJobNumber \tCostPerHour x HoursWorked + CostOfMaterials = CostOfJob");
        for(int i = 0; i>jobs.size(); i++){
            System.out.println(jobs.get(i).getDate()+"\t"+jobs.get(i).getJobNumber()+"\t"+jobs.get(i).getCostPerHour()+" x "+jobs.get(i).getHoursWorked()+" + "+jobs.get(i).getCostOfMaterials()+" = "+jobs.get(i).getCostOfJob());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *"i can't seem to get it to work."* Can you explain what exactly is not working?

Comment: In your PrintJobs method you have this `i>jobs.size()` which should be `i<jobs.size()` if you want to get anything printed...

Comment: Also, you might want to use the collections `for` loop; this makes your code less error prone.

Comment: actually jpw was right, the only error was the ">" sign, i fixed it, thanks guys

Comment: @ShazuHassen You might want to look into how to override the `toString()` method for objects.

Answer (score 2):

This is cleaner. You might even consider using `System.out.printf`.

```
public static void PrintJobs()
{
     System.out.println("Date \tJobNumber \tCostPerHour x HoursWorked + 
     CostOfMaterials = CostOfJob");
     for(Job j: jobs)
     {                     
         System.out.println(j.getDate()+ "\t"+ j.getJobNumber()+  ...
     }
}
```